# 301 redirect any RSS feed on level up url

Tags: redirect, htaccess

On my site I've got RSS feeds - something like this:

- `www.example.com/en/shipper/feed/`
- `www.example.com/en/carrier/feed/`

I want to 301 redirect all those URLs to the level up, respectively:

- `www.example.com/en/shipper/`
- `www.example.com/en/carrier/`

Answer (score 2):

So to redirect /en/shipper/feed/ to /en/shipper you should be able to add this in your **root** .htaccess. You'll have to make sure you put it in the right place so that it gets matched *before* any other Rewrite rules - putting it at the top of the list of RewriteRule's should be fine.

These rules assume that you have a standard Wordpress .htaccess with `RewriteBase /`

```
RewriteRule ^en/shipper/feed/$ /en/shipper/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^en/carrier/feed/$ /en/carrier/ [R=301,L]
```

I tested a similar rule in a test setup and it works for me.

Comment: Ok, but i got 28 language version and want redirect ANY url with "feed" on level up in one line rule

Comment: Ah, your question didn't say that. So what are the specifics of what you need? Any two letter language and then specifically 'shipper' or 'carrier' ?

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding. At the moment wordpress adds "feed" to each url. For SEO reasons this is undesirable and I want to avoid it. I don't know - maybe doing it through .htaccess is not a good way?

Comment: No, it could be - I was just asking specifically what the other variations of URL's are you want to redirect. If the above two rules work well for those specific cases it's easy to make another rule which matches whatever the other cases are.

Comment: I guess you're aware that Wordpress makes a /feed/ URL to provide e.g. a RSS feed for the blog or e.g. for specific categories? If you forward that URL to a different page then anyone trying to get the feed won't be able to access it. Maybe you just want to turn the feeds off?

Comment: OK, thanks for advise!